# Sitecore 7 ContentSearchManager No Results

Tags: c#, search, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I have upgraded to `Sitecore 7.1` in my dev environment and refactoring some areas in the application that were getting items, trying to use the new `ContentSearchManager`. Through code or through `LinqPad` I am getting no results but when debugging with Luke the index does have items.

Test code that doesn't return anything:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
      context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where (item  => item.Name == "Home");
}
```

Can someone tell me the best way to debug and get this wired up?

Comment: Do you get any results if you remove the Where filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems incomplete.  I would expect to see something along the lines of the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
    var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index");
    using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
    {
        IQueryable<SearchResultItem> query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where (item  => item.Name == "Home");

        SearchResults<SearchResultItem> results = query.GetResults();

        return results.Hits.Select(hit => hit.Document.GetItem());
    }
}
```

If that is unsuccessful, you should be able to see the raw Lucene query when debugging the `query` object in Visual Studio.  I would recommend validating that query matches the query you have been running in Luke.  It's possible the API is applying additional filter expressions to your query.